# Visual Studio 2019 Blazor serverside project is soooooo slow

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, blazor

I am working on a Blazor project and the texteditor is very very slow when working in the .Razor files.
In the .CS, .xml and so on, everything is fine, but in the mixed .Razor it ie. takes up to 3-5 sec. to do a if()
{} and I get this:

[Screendump link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kohUN.jpg)

Does anyone know a trick or a tweek to get the VS 2019 texteditor useful again?

Comment: Did you turn it off and back on again? Maybe disable any "helpful" extensions?

Comment: Close Error list panel

Comment: If the above items don't help (which they both should) 1) toggle intellisense from completion to suggestion mode, or vice versa. 2) Back up your config for VS, then do a repair on the installation. 3) Maybe run a registry cleaner utility and restart computer? (Seems to help for me for both VS and AutoCAD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only use Razor files for rendering the markup. For any logic I create a code behind file by creating a file named MyComponent.Razor.cs

```
public partial class MyComponent
{
  // Supporting methods etc go here
}
```

It's a better experience!

Comment: And then turn all those Intellisense features back on again. This is better, just not for the actual UI part. It is a partial solution.